# blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vda, sector on KVM QEMU virtual machine

Tags: linux, boot, hard-disk, kvm, fsck

Following my System76 Debian laptop battery drained and the computer shut down, I could not boot the device that I could solve with a live cd and `fsck -y` but the QEMU/KVM virtual machine it contained cannot be booted because the issue at the bottom.

I tried to fix it using the same method: mounting a live cd and running fsck, but that exists with error code 9.

I'm wondering if is this different to fix because of the VDA disk that contains my /home directory.
How do you make it boot again?
Thank you for any help :pray:

```
/dev/vda1: clean, 1811334/15863040 files, 14275857/63692544 blocks 
[ 2.767035] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vda, sector 515741952 op Ox0:( READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0 
[ 2.776713] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vda, sector 515742552 op Ox0:( READ) flags Ox0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0 
[ 2.777028] Buffer I/O error on dev vda6, logical block 524395, async page re ad [ 2.778294] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vda, sector 515742552 op Ox0:( READ) flags Ox0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0 
[ 2.778538] Buffer I/O error on dev vda6, logical block 524395, async page re ad [ 2.779791] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vda, sector 515742552 op Ox0:( READ) flags Ox0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0 
[ 2.779792] Buffer I/O error on dev vda6, logical block 524395, async page re ad [ 2.780884] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vda, sector 515742552 op Ox0:( READ) flags Ox0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0 
[ 2.780885] Buffer I/O error on dev vda6, logical block 524395, async page re ad "(
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running a QEMU/KVM-Setup (managed by libvirtd) and ran into that error recently. Idid not find any useful resources that provided any deeper insight or even a solution.

After tinkering around with most settings I felt could be having an impact what actually solved this problem was this:

1. Stop the VM
2. Remove the image from the VM (i.E. it had no image at all at this point) and apply the changes/save the new configuration
3. Re-Add the exact same image to the VM-Definition and save again.

For me these errors disappeared and I really don't know why. Still searching for an explanation.